# Upstart service killed by TERM signal, how to track that

Tags: python, services, signals, upstart

I have upstart script as

```
description "My API API"
author "me@localhost"

env MY_API_PYTHON_HOME=/opt/services

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

script
  mkfifo /tmp/my-api-log-fifo
  ( logger -t my-api </tmp/my-api-log-fifo & )
  exec >/tmp/my-api-log-fifo
  rm /tmp/my-api-log-fifo
  exec $MY_API_PYTHON_HOME/script_api_virt/bin/python $MY_API_PYTHON_HOME/my_api.py 2>/dev/null
end script

# Restart the process if it dies with a signal
# or exit code not given by the 'normal exit' stanza.
respawn

# Give up if restart occurs 10 times in 90 seconds.
respawn limit 10 90
```

When I enable the debug log, its showing

```
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.553365] init: job_class_register: Registered job /com/ubuntu/Upstart/jobs/ureadahead
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.553692] init: my-api goal changed from start to stop
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.553742] init: my-api state changed from running to pre-stop
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.553776] init: my-api state changed from pre-stop to stopping
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.553808] init: event_new: Pending stopping event
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.553823] init: Handling stopping event
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.553889] init: event_finished: Finished stopping event
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.553895] init: my-api state changed from stopping to killed
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.553935] init: Sending TERM signal to my-api main process (25787)
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.556636] init: my-api main process (25787) killed by TERM signal
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.556689] init: my-api state changed from killed to post-stop
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.556735] init: my-api state changed from post-stop to waiting
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.556768] init: event_new: Pending stopped event
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.556783] init: job_change_state: Destroyed inactive instance my-api
Oct  3 19:50:48 localhost kernel: [6732712.556837] init: Handling stopped event
```

Upstart has `respawn` logic, and my service start automatically, but I want to know why its stoping with `TERM` singal.

How to track, who is stoping this service ?

When I run command `exec $MY_API_PYTHON_HOME/script_api_virt/bin/python $MY_API_PYTHON_HOME/my_api.py` it ran for 12 hours without any error.